# Suggestions to Optimize Blocking Queue implementation

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

```
T BlockingQueue<T>::pop( ) { 
       pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
       if (list.empty( )) { 
           pthread_cond_wait(&cond) ;
       }
       T temp = list.front( );
       list.pop_front( );
       pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
       return temp;
}
```

The above is the pop operation as defined for a templatized concurrent blocking queue based on an underlying linked list and pthreads. My question: In what ways could we optimize this code further?

Comment: Off-topic, but you should wrap the lock/unlocking into a class. Look up SBRM/RAII. On-topic, looks like further improvement could only be found via a lock-free queue.

Comment: @GMan - would the RAII metaphor still work when the lock is linked to the condition variable, as here? just curious...

Comment: @GMan - don't worry, found my answer here: http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/implementing-a-thread-safe-queue-using-condition-variables.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concurrency handling look pretty minimal.  Your underlying container is the best candidate for perf tuning.  Is this really a linked list?  `deque` would be better if you are doing FIFO ops only.

EDIT: see also sample code from Anthony Williams (who wrote current Boost.Thread) [here](http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/implementing-a-thread-safe-queue-using-condition-variables.html), for tips and detailed discussion.

Answer (score 0):

In your current solution, what is the specific problem which you try to achieve by further optimization?